# Laravel orWhere() / MySQL or query taking a long time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 4.2 and my application is used for tracking inventory across multiple locations.

The database is set up with an `inventory_items` table, `inventory_locations` table and a pivot table between them `inventory_items_inventory_location`, which contains the quantity values whilst referencing both the inventory item and location the record belongs to.

My query is to find inventory items that have any location quantity value more than or equal to 0. In Laravel I'm using a subquery and orWhere like so:

```
InventoryItem::whereHas('inventoryLocations', function($q) {
  $q->where('reserved', '>=', 0)
     ->orWhere('available', '>=', 0) # slow
     ->orWhere('inbound', '>=', 0) # slow
     ->orWhere('total', '>=', 0); # slow
})->toSql();
```

Which gives the following SQL:

```
select * from `inventory_items`
where `inventory_items`.`deleted_at` is null
and (
  select count(*) from `inventory_locations`
  inner join `inventory_item_inventory_location`
  on `inventory_locations`.`id` = `inventory_item_inventory_location`.`inventory_location_id` 
  where `inventory_item_inventory_location`.`inventory_item_id` = `inventory_items`.`id`
  and `reserved` >= ?
  or `available` >= ? # slow
  or `inbound` >= ? # slow
  or `total` >= ? # slow
) >= 1
```

The problem is that with the `or` statements (marked in the code by `#slow`) the query time is up to 1s directly with Sequel Pro, more than 5s through my Laravel app (or through artisan tinker). Without these 'or' checks (i.e. just checking for one quantity type e.g. 'reserved') the query is <100ms on Sequel Pro and similar on the app/tinker.

I'm not sure why adding these extra 'or' checks adds so much time to the query. Any ideas how to make a more performant query?

Comment: have You added indexes on table's `reserved`, `available`, `inbound`, `total` fields ?

Comment: In generally "or" condition make possibilities of query execution. Also database engine never make static path, when you use these type of dynamic conditions. So it might take more time than per-preparred path

Comment: @num8er yes, I have indexes on each and have tried a multiple index too (not sure the proper terminology for that)

Comment: @ShankarThiyagaraajan not 100% sure what you mean - could you provide a simple example?

Comment: How many rows are in your table? Also, am I correct in assuming that you can have negative values for your `available`, `inbound` and `total`?

Comment: @MrOffice if You've added already indexes on every field, so I can guess You to change logic of comparing from `>=` to `>` cuz I don't see logic of `whereHas('inventoryLocations')`. I mean You need to check `inventoryLocations` existence if data is more than zero. cuz `>=` might return all data.

Comment: @RossWilson Only 5k rows. Negative values are allowed, but there aren't any currently.

Comment: @num8er Thanks - the change in comparison doesn't affect anything - I've tried with `=, >, <` etc.

Comment: Thanks guys, @jedzrej.kurylo nailed it on the head.

Comment: @Mr Office, In General "where" class will make Step-by-Step level filter. But "orWhere" is little different. The Filter process will totally change with or without previous filter (previous "Where"). So every time you uses "orWhere", it will dynamically change its flow. So it might take noticeable time delay.

Comment: @Mr Office, Ex. Consider, Student List. Totally 100 records as Name|FirstName|LastName|Email. 

Query : "select * from students where lastName like '%john%' or email like '%sales%';"

Here, its generate 3 possible Probabilities, 
1. LastName like '%john%',
2. email like '%sales%',
3. LastName like '%john%' or email like '%sales%'

These three will fired Dynamically !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the resulting query and its **WHERE** conditions. You definitely miss some brackets there, as I guess what you need is

```
where `inventory_item_inventory_location`.`inventory_item_id` = `inventory_items`.`id`
and (
   `reserved` >= ?
   or `available` >= ? #
   or `inbound` >= ?
   or `total` >= ?
)
```

instead of

```
where `inventory_item_inventory_location`.`inventory_item_id` = `inventory_items`.`id`
and `reserved` >= ?
or `available` >= ? # slow
or `inbound` >= ? # slow
or `total` >= ?
```

It results in full table scan which is terribly slow for tables with high amount of rows.

In order to fix that, replace

```
InventoryItem::whereHas('inventoryLocations', function($q) {
  $q->where('reserved', '>=', 0)
   ->orWhere('available', '>=', 0) # slow
   ->orWhere('inbound', '>=', 0) # slow
   ->orWhere('total', '>=', 0); # slow
})->toSql();
```

with

```
InventoryItem::whereHas('inventoryLocations', function($q) {
  $q->where(function($subquery) {
    $subquery->where('reserved', '>=', 0)
     ->orWhere('available', '>=', 0)
     ->orWhere('inbound', '>=', 0)
     ->orWhere('total', '>=', 0);
  });
})->toSql();
```

Check out MySQL's **EXPLAIN** command that lets you analyse how query will be executed and how many rows will be queried - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Comment: Perfect - makes sense to subquery it now I know a bit more about how it works. Will look into explain in the future to debug this sort of issue. Thanks